# How Should I Include Bond in C++ Visual Studio Project?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, bond

I'm following the C++ on Windows instructions on https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/ but it isn't clear how to include and use Bond from a native C++ project in Visual Studio.  I've read both that Bond needs to be compiled as part of my project and that I should use Bond's .lib file to speed up builds.  What are the correct steps after I download all the dependencies and get CMake to build Bond so that I can get sample code from the documentation working in my project?  I want to run and debug code which uses Bond from within Visual Studio.  Thanks

Comment: SO is not for code writing!!

Answer (score 1):

This answer has now been incorporated into the Bond C++ documentation: [Integrating Bond into your build](https://microsoft.github.io/bond/manual/bond_cpp.html#integrating-bond-into-your-build). Relevant excerpts:

> To consume Bond, you will need to integrate it into your build somehow. If
>   you are using one of these C++ package managers, Bond is available as a
>   package that you can consume:
>
> - [Vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/vcpkg)'s `bond` package
>
> What follows are build-system agnostic instructions for consuming C++ Bond.
>
> These instructions assume that you have used
>   [Bond's CMake-based build](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/README.md) to
>   compile and *install* (`make install`/`cmake --build . --target INSTALL`)
>   Bond into your development environment somewhere. The CMake variable
>   `CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX` can be used to control where the install target
>   places the output files.
>
> (The Bond CMake files can't currently be consumed by another CMake project
>   via `add_directory`.
>   [Contributions encouraged](https://github.com/Microsoft/bond/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md)
>   to help improve this situation.)
>
> After you've built and installed Bond, you can use whatever build system you need by
>
> 1. teaching it how to automatically run code generation on .bond files;
> 2. configuring your C++ compiler's `#include` search path to point at Boost
>      and Bond; and
> 3. configuring your linker's library path to have the Boost and Bond
>      libraries on its search path.
>
> Step #1 is very build system dependent. Contributions of these build systems
>   rules to the Bond repository will be happily accepted.
>
> When building the library/executable that is going to use Bond, you'll need
>   to set your compiler's `#include` search path to point to:
>
> - where your version of Boost is installed
> - where your version of Bond is installed
>
> If you use any types from bond.bond (e.g., by using an `import`
>   statement in your .bond file or by using the C++ `RuntimeSchema`
>   APIs), you will also need to link the library/executable with Bond
>   (The names may vary depending on platform/toolset.):
>
> - `libbond.a`/`bond.lib` and
> - optionally, `libbond_apply.a`/`bond_apply.lib`, if you plan to `#include <bond/core/bond_apply.h>`.

You will need to adapt these for your chosen build system.